# Class method calling another class' method that is stored as an argument

Tags: javascript, function, class, methods, arguments

Sorry for the confusing title, I have no clue how to ask this.
I have a question regarding classes and methods. I have a button that, when pressed, calls another object's function. For this example, it should log "100" to the console as f's "x", but instead, it logs "0": my button's "x".  Help?

```
<script>
function fun(x){
    this.x = x;
}

fun.prototype = {
    s:function(){
        console.log(this.x);
    }
}

function Button(func){
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.w = 1000;
    this.h = 1000;
    this.func = func;
}

Button.prototype = {
    check_if_click:function(x, y){
       if (x >= this.x && x <= this.x + this.w && y >= this.y && y <= this.y + this.h){
            this.func();
        }
    }
}

f = new fun(100);
b = new Button(f.s);
b.check_if_click(500, 500);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind a function to a certain context, you can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). It creates a copy of a function where `this` is set to whatever you pass to it.

```
b = new Button(f.s.bind(f));
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`this` in a function is bound to whatever you called it from. So calling,

```
this.func();
```

Is the exact same thing as calling

```
b.func();
```

Which means that `this` in `func` will get bound to `b`. That's why `console.log(this.x)` prints `0`: because `b.x` is `0`.